# c segmentation fault structure

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have a structure called table, I just want to create a table, like constructor in java, but when i call this function in main, it gives segmentation fault

```
struct table *create(char *name,int number,char *s_name)
{
  struct table *newTable;
  newTable->name = name;
  newTable->number = number;
  newTable->s_name = s_name;
  return newTable;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
struct table *newTable = malloc(sizeof(struct table));
```

Don't forget calling free when you're done using it, as C does not have a Garbage Collector like java has.

Comment: That should be either `sizeof (struct table)` or `sizeof *newTable` (I prefer the latter).  Unlike C++, struct tags must be preceded by the `struct` keyword.

Answer (score 9):

You haven't allocated any memory for the object, and are de-referencing fields of the structure. You need to use malloc to allocate memory for newTable before accessing it

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to access unallocated/uninitialized memory & SIGSEGV (Segmentation Fault) is perfectly alright for the code unless you allocate memory explicitly using malloc or other memory allocation methods.